# Explain how the for loop is terminating?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I came across the a code which I didn't understand. It was on a coding website. The code was like this-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

char s[4];
int x;
int main()
{
for(cin>>s;cin>>s;x+=44-s[1]);
cout<<x;
}
```

My question is **how the for loop is terminating** and since it was on a coding website so answers are checked using file operation in my knowledge. But if we are running it on IDE this for loop is not terminating instead it keeps on taking input from the user.So whats the explanation for this??

**Sample Input**

3

x++

x--

--x

Output

-1

**EDIT**

This is the problem link - [Bit++](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A)

This is the solution link - [In status filter set language to MS C++ Author name - wafizaini (Solution id - 27116030)](http://codeforces.com/problemset/status/282/problem/A)

Comment: Whatever coding website it is, run away from it. Variables are declared outside functions, and 'x' is unitialized.

Comment: @Fabien "and 'x' is unitialized." It is?

Comment: @Fabien -- `x` is defined in global scope, so it is (implicitly) initialized to 0.

Comment: It is declared and left unitialized. The loop does a `+=` not an assignation so it increments `x` without taking in account its original value. There is no such thing as 'implicitely initialized to 0`, this is all left to the compiler and so is a terrible code portability practice.

Comment: @Fabien -- again: global scope variables are initialized to 0 if they do not have an explicit initializer. Look it up.

Comment: @Pete you are right on this for the global variables. So my bad, it went out of my mind.

Comment: Wait a second while i write this down in my "Book of things to never do in C++".  This has to be some of the most gruesome code i have ever seen.

Comment: Read my edit post for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is terminating because `istream` has `operator bool()` (prior to C++11 it was `operator void*`) which returns `false` when no additional input is available. Basically, the reason the loop stops is the same as why a more common `while` loop terminates:

```
while (cin >> s) {
    ...
}
```

The reason this does not terminate when you run with an IDE is that you need to supply an end-of-stream mark, which is delivered in a system-dependent way. On UNIX and other systems derived from it you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, while on Windows you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

**Note:** Your program is at risk of getting a buffer overrun in case an end-user enters more than three characters (character #4 would be used for null terminator of the string). Also note that the initial input `cin>>s` is thrown away, because loop condition is checked before entering the body of the loop.

Comment: One question I am using Dev C++ 5.11 on Windows 8.1 platform . If u press Ctrl+Z it displays ^Z and when I m typing ^Z it is working differently.Whats the reason for that?

Comment: @Ash I am not sure if Dev C++ console handles it properly. Run exe produced by the compiler on the command line, and press Ctrl+Z when you want to end input stream.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly valid, although a bit difficult to read, C++11 code.

```
std::istream::operator>>()
```

returns a reference to the input stream itself, and

```
std::istream::operator bool()
```

in turn evaluates the stream to a boolean value, returning false whenever a fail bit is set.

When reading from a file, that loop will eventually try to read past the end of file, causing the eof fail bit to be set and thus stopping the loop.

However, when running that code on a shell, you need to manually input the EOF control code on the stream, otherwise the for loop won't stop. This can be done by pressing Ctrl+D on Unix shells, for example.

Answer (score 0):

A more common loop condition is `while (cin >> s)`.

The convention is that `operator>>` returns a reference to the stream (`cin`). The stream classes then have a conversion operator that will return `false` in `if (cin)` or `while (cin)` after some input has failed.

This would work in the middle part of a `for`-loop as well, but is a bit unusual.